# Realm(android), AsyncTask. Does not beginTransaction

Tags: android, android-asynctask, realm

У меня есть AsynckTask

```
 @Override
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
 Realm realm;
 ...
 realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
 realm.beginTransaction();
 Log.d(TAG,"start transaction");
 ...
}
```

При запуске компилятор не идет дальше `realm.beginTransaction();`,

Строка `Log.d(TAG,"start transaction");` не попадает в лог и метод `onPostExecute`

Comment: А проверили по логам, код доходит до строки перед `beginTransaction()`?

Comment: Да, доходит, код не выполняется лишь после

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но вроде в Realm транзакции синхронны, независимо от потока. У Вас в другом потоке случайно не держится открытая транзакция для дефолтного инстанса?

Comment: на автообновление данных держится в другом потоке

Comment: Обновлять данные нужно не держа открытой транзакцию, а при перезаписи начинать и коммитить. Никогда не держите открытой транзакцию, когда не происходит непосредственного обновления.